# What is the difference between getShippingAddress and getDefaultShippingAddress

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I need to get the shipping address of logged in customer and guest customer on checkout page.

I am able to get shipping address from both the method if customer in logged in, but I am not sure which one should I use, basically difference between these two methods.

```
getShippingAddress() and getDefaultShippingAddress()
```

Answer (score 0):

Default Billing address is a address that is selected as "Default" in my account section.

It will be auto selected when checkout.

Reference

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tj7sN2yViChnPMtjsLnWoV_XsNeekQr6/view

Thanks